# Quickly determine if code is Visual C++ or not

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Is there a quick way to determine whether a Visual Studio C++ project is written in plain C++ or Visual C++?

Comment: Visual Studio has some pre-defined Macros. Here is a table of them on MSDN: href='http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any files include the lines `#pragma once` or `#include "stdafx.h"`, it's very likely Visual C++.

(Are there any other compilers that implement `#pragma once`?)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `#pragma once` originated on (and is still supported by) gcc.

Answer (score 1):

No -- Visual C++ will compile most plain C++ without any problems. If you want to check for use of Windows-specific "stuff", checking for inclusion (directly or indirectly) of `<windows.h>` would probably be a reasonable start.

Answer (score 0):

If is Visual C++ it usually has a project.sln or project.vcproj file in the project directory.

Comment: Yes but you can have plain C++ *.vcproj files as well.